# PHPMailer Not Sending Emails - Am I missing something simple?

Tags: php, html-email, phpmailer, ob-start

I am using [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=phpmailer) to send HTML emails. I first set the HTML body of the email using HTML and PHP variables after first calling `ob_start`.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

ob_start();
?>

..... a bunch of VALID HTML

<?
$body = ob_get_contents();

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

// Send to Me
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
$mail->IsSendmail(); // telling the class to use SendMail transport

try {
    $mail->AddReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Company Name');
    $mail->AddAddress('me@example.com', 'My Name');
    $mail->SetFrom('info@example.com', 'Company Name');
    $mail->Subject  =  "Contact Form Confirmation";
    $mail->AltBody    = "This is a contact form submitted through the main website.";
    $mail->WordWrap   =  50; // set word wrap   
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

    $mail->Send(); // Try to send email

    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
// end try
```

For some reason, this line:

```
$mail->Body = $body;
```

causes the email not to send.  If I replace it with:

```
$mail->Body = "This is a test email.";
```

the email sends perfectly.

If my HTML contained within `$body` is just a valid HTML page with CSS in the head, and no Javascript or anything, why won't the email send?

Is there another way to do this? Please help!!

Comment: var_dump($body). It might have been reset halfway through it (no telling what's in the include).

Comment: Good Idea!! Where can I put that in order to see what's going on??

Comment: Are any exceptions being thrown? If so, what does the message say?

Comment: Put it just above $mail->Body = $body; so you know exactly what was set.

Comment: It shows `string(22590) "` in the HTML... what is that?

Comment: That's the number of characters in the string. So, the string isn't reset, which means that your email is dropped further down the line. Do you have access to the server logs and/or bounceback messages?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the string isn't reset" ?
Also, is this what's causing the `$mail->Body = $body;` to not send the email?

Comment: Is there a way to tell `ob_start()` to STOP recording at a certain point? Eg. if I have my HTML and then say "don't include after `</html>`" ?

Comment: call `ob_end_clean()` after ob_get_contents()

Comment: I added that, but the emails still aren't sending. Is there any way with PHPMailer to find out why...? This seemed to be working fine a week ago.

Comment: Just and idea but I'm sending html emails using phpMailer on my localhost and i use file_get_contents('html_file.html') that way i can point it to the file i would like to send. I have not looked into if this is secure for us on a server but its easy to do and might be worth looking into.

Comment: This could be a dumb question but where is you $mail->Host, $mail->port, $mail->username, $mail->Password? I didn't think PHPMailer had any defaults for these?

Comment: I'm not sending via SMTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, for some reason, the emails were not sending if they contained a fax number. Totally strange. I tested my entire markup, and after ONLY removing a 10 digit phone number, the emails finally went through. I'm not a newbie - literally that's the only text I removed and the emails sent fine.

HAS ANYONE SEEN THIS BEFORE??